# Next.js unable to get async data in HOC

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm writing a HOC that will get the user data from my API, then pass props to the wrapped component so it can redirect the user if they don't have the correct role.

My HOC is below, however the `getInitialProps` function doesn't trigger.   The HOC is working in principal though as the `myNum` prop is passed down.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function routeRedirect(C) {
  return class Higher extends Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
      console.log('GIP');
      await fetch('/api/getUsers');
    }

    render() {
      return <C {...this.props} myNum={42} />;
    }
  };
}

export default routeRedirect;
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: How are you calling that function?

Comment: I export my Dashboard layout like `export default routeRedirect(Dashboard)`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't returning the fetched data from `getInitialProps`.

In the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) it says : "Data *returned* from getInitialProps is serialized when server rendering...".